# Openserach url with "+"

Tags: c#, asp.net, opensearch

Good morning,

Sorry my english, I have a problem with opensearch when I generate url with character "+" when searching more than one word. I read about "allowDoubleEscaping" in web.config, but seems to be dangerous. Is there something I can do to replace "+" for "-" before the search?

Comment: i forgot to say, i using asp.net and i need make this in the global.asax, but i not have assurance.

Comment: Having a `+` in a url in place of a space is perfectly valid.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far? Share your code and please review [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: you can use '%20' instead

Comment: @RamonCaetano welcome to SO! Please include *all relevant* information into your post, try not to add important details about your issue/s in the comments section, if you do, please make sure to add them to your OP. For now, I went ahead and made these changes for you.

Comment: the problem occurs when a user searches the browser search engine and returns error 404.11

Comment: I thought using allowDoubleEscaping, but I read what's so dangerous for security.